# Working with checkboxes in tkinter (pygubu)

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, pygubu

I created a window with the GUI maker pygubu. This window contains checkboxes. But my script is not able to recognize if the checkboxes are marked or not.
How do I have to check if the checkboxes are marked or not?
Do Ihave to use the command or the variable? What is the right syntax?

Below you can see what I have done in pygubu. How do I get the state of my checkbox?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9o5A.jpg

I tried:

```
def checker13(self, variable=check13):
    self.variable13 = variable
    print self.variable13
```

This should print me the state of the checkbox everytime something changed. But I always receive an error. What can I do?

Comment: How can we explain bugs in the code without seeing the code?

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried to be more precise. Maybe you can help me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an inelegant way to do it. It's not very "pretty", but it works:

```
self.xxx1 = 0 
def checker13(self):
    if self.xxx1 == 0:
        self.xxx1 = self.xxx1+1
    else:
        self.xxx1 = 0
```

Normally the checkbox is not marked and the value is `0`. If the checkbox gets marked there is an event and the value changes to `1`. The next event changes the value back to `0`. By this method I can check the state of the checkbox by checking `xxx1`.

I knew there are other ways (with `IntVar()`) but I was specifically searching for a solution with pygubu. If there is a smoother answer feel free to correct me.

EDIT: 
to get the value of an variable from pygubu use:

```
variable = self.builder.get_variable('variable')
variable = variable.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the example from here http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_checkboxes.php

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="male", variable=var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="female", variable=var2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
mainloop()
```

You need to set a variable that stores the result of the checkbox and then reference that (in this example it's var1 and var2).

Edit: to more specifically answer your question; you can check the result of `var1` and `var2` as they will either equal `0` for not checked or `1` for checked. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not really helping me. I tried to be more precise. Maybe you can check my edited post?

Comment: You needed to be more specific from the outset. Hopefully someone can answer your question based on this new info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying your question. Now that I know you're using Pygubu to build your GUI, I could look into it a little more. I found the following doc page that could help with your issue:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Checkbutton.html

The key Checkbutton option to pay attention to is the `variable` option. In the image you gave, it looks like you tried setting the `variable` option to `var`. The doc above says this about the `variable` option:

> A control variable that tracks the current state of the checkbutton...
>   Normally you will use an IntVar here, and the off and on values are 0
>   and 1, respectively.

Do you have the option to change the `variable` option to be an `IntVar`, instead of the `int` that it currently is in the picture? If not, then that should still be fine.

So, the variable `var` will store the state of the Checkbutton. In the picture you gave, you set the `command` option to be `checker13`. Keep it like that. Now, since I've never used Pygubu (or even Tkinter for that matter), I can't be sure that this code will work, but try something like this:

```
def checker13(self):
    print(self.var)
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
def checker13(self):
    print(self.variable)
```

If one of those works, let me know so I can edit my answer with the working code. If you're still stuck, let me know as well.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not really helping me. I tried to be more precise. Maybe you can check my edited post?

Comment: I changed my answer. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: No i did not work. I got another error
`AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'var'`

Comment: I found another solution. You can check it out if you are interested :D

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.  Below is a simplified solution just dealing with the checkbox.

checkbox_example.py contents:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder() # Create builder
        builder.add_from_file('checkbox_example.ui') # Load ui file.

        # Create widget using master as parent
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainwindow', master)

        builder.connect_callbacks(self) # Connect callbacks

        # Create check button object
        self.check_button_object = builder.get_object('cb0', self.mainwindow)

    def on_checkbox_clicked(self):
        print("on_checkbox_clicked")
        checked = self.builder.get_variable('checked') # Get variable
        print(checked.get()) # get value of checked and print it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk,Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and the content of checkbox_example.ui is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<interface>
  <object class="tk.Frame" id="mainwindow">
    <property name="height">200</property>
    <property name="width">200</property>
    <layout>
      <property name="column">0</property>
      <property name="propagate">True</property>
      <property name="row">0</property>
      <property name="sticky">nw</property>
    </layout>
    <child>
      <object class="tk.Checkbutton" id="cb0">
        <property name="command">on_checkbox_clicked</property>
        <property name="cursor">arrow</property>
        <property name="font">TkDefaultFont</property>
        <property name="offvalue">0</property>
        <property name="onvalue">1</property>
        <property name="pady">0</property>
        <property name="text" translatable="yes">checkbox_string</property>
        <property name="underline">0</property>
        <property name="variable">int:checked</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">0</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">1</property>
        </layout>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

To see it executed, I've created a short youtube clip: 
https://youtu.be/Y6lpi3oihOo